# Why does synaptic want me to uninstall half my programs just to get wine? 

Tags: installation, dependencies, lubuntu, winetricks

I have noticed it lately, so I am suspicious it is something to do with being on a 64 bit install. I especially notice when trying uninstalling something I don't want by KDE; I seem to have to choose between installing them all, or keeping the one I don't want.

Wine seems to want me to uninstall my entire desktop. It is not good enough to be making demands like that of me so I would be interested to know if there is a way to bypass it.

I like to install `winetricks` specifically but it would be good to know the workaround for similar situations. I am using Lubuntu 64bit.

Here's what happens when I try to install winetricks

```
sudo apt-get install winetricks 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
 libsaevt3 libopenal1 libopencc1 libkresources4 libsoundtouch0 libkldap4
  libtwolame0 libradiusclient-ng2 libva-x11-1 libzbar0 xsltproc libzvbi-common
  libksane0 authbind libiksemel3 libkxmlrpcclient4 fcitx-modules
  libconfig-inifiles-perl libgmime-2.6-0 tellico-data swh-plugins libpload4
  libsbsms10 libsrtp0 libpg-java gstreamer0.10-fluendo-mp3 libvotequorum4
  libaspectj-java libsam4 fcitx-ui-classic libzvbi0 libportsmf0 libcfg4
  libconfdb4 libcoroipcc4 libflac++6 libboost-program-options1.46.1
  libhsqldb-java libsqlite0 libslv2-9 libcoroipcs4 clamav-base libopenal-data
  liblogsys4 libclamav6 texlive-bibtex-extra libboost-iostreams1.46.1 tofrodos
  libcpg4 freetds-common libqjson0 libosgi-foundation-ee-java
  gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg aspectj libexempi3 libkabc4 libvpb0 libcurl3 libyaz4
  libgme0 libspandsp2 freepats ladspa-sdk libosgi-core-java libspeexdsp1
  libevs4 audacity-data libkcal4 libboost-thread1.46.1 libwildmidi1
  asterisk-moh-opsound-gsm libserp-java libkate1 libcdaudio1 libmimic0
  libsybdb5 libsaclm3 libkmime4 libwildmidi-config libksane-data libmad0
  libpq5 libtommath0 libquorum4 liboil0.3 fcitx-module-dbus fcitx-module-x11
  asterisk-config libvamp-hostsdk3 libkpimutils4 libcelt0-0 libodbc1
  libgstreamer-plugins-bad0.10-0 tellico-scripts libtotem-pg4 libsvn-perl
  fxload libmpcdec6 asterisk-core-sounds-en-gsm libcorosync4 libresample1
  libofa0 libpostgresql-jdbc-java vpb-driver-source unixodbc
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  fonts-horai-umefont fonts-unfonts-core libao-common libao4 libgl1-mesa-glx
  libpng12-0:i386 libsox-fmt-ao ttf-unfonts-core unixodbc zlib1g:i386
Suggested packages:
  libroar1 libsndio0 roaraudio-server
Recommended packages:
  wine1.4 wine cxoffice5 cxgames5
The following packages will be REMOVED 
  alsa-firmware alsa-firmware-loaders alsa-utils ant1.7-gcj asterisk
  asterisk-modules asterisk-voicemail audacious audacious-plugins audacity
  bluez-alsa browser-plugin-gnash chromium-browser chromium-browser-l10n
  chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra gcj-4.6-jre-lib gnash gnash-common
  gnome-screenshot gstreamer0.10-alsa gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad kbibtex
  kde-runtime kile kile-l10n konsole libasound2 libbonoboui2-0
  libcanberra-gtk3-0 libcanberra0 libesd0 libflite1 libfluidsynth1 libgcj-bc
  libgcj12 libgl1-mesa-swx11 libgl1-mesa-swx11-dbg libglu1-mesa libgmlib0
  libgmtk0 libgnome2-0 libgnomeui-0 libjmathtex-java-gcj libkcddb4
  libkonq-common libkonq5abi1 libokularcore1abi1 libportaudio2 libpurple0
  libsasl2-modules libsdl1.2debian libsox-fmt-alsa lubuntu-core lxde-core
  lxpanel lxpanel-dbg lxpanel-indicator-applet-plugin mplayer2
  notification-daemon octave3.2 okular okular-extra-backends pdftk phonon
  phonon-backend-gstreamer pidgin pidgin-latex pidgin-microblog
  python-subversion subversion subversion-tools tellico update-notifier
  winefish xorg
  The following NEW packages will be installed
   fonts-horai-umefont fonts-unfonts-core libao-common libao4 libgl1-mesa-glx
  libpng12-0:i386 libsox-fmt-ao ttf-unfonts-core unixodbc winetricks
  zlib1g:i386
```

Some of them look blatantly like they are 32bit but I will be impressed if anyone knows how to wade through that!

I should mention that

`lubuntu-core lxde-core lxpanel`

are quite important to me.

Comment: can you post the exact packages it wants to remove while removing WINE.

Comment: i want to install winetricks actually. It's just this happens when I try to remove things sometimes too.

Comment: It has scared them off, that has.

Comment: Is wine 1.4 or 1.5 already installed in system

Comment: no there are no wine files on there already

Comment: I think may be synaptic is trying to update or upgrade those files to x64.

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused by some packages not being upgraded to the latest version. I have noticed this behavior sometimes (on a 32-bit install). Upgrading all packages to the latest version solves it.

I think the reason for this is that the new package you are trying to install is incompatible with the currently installed version of other packages. Instead of upgrading these, the package manager decides to remove them.

I normally run `sudo aptitude full-upgrade` to fix this, though `apt-get` should do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The most probable cause of this problem may be, you have packages installed which is conflicting with the packages you requested to install i.e winetricks and it's dependencies.

The actual cause of this conflict can be several, but I guess this one:

- You may have updated packages installed which are incompatible with requested packages for installation, in that case `apt-get` or synaptic try to remove those packages. Most of the time, it happens when we use cutting-edge PPAs.

My recommendation would be this:

1. First enable all repository and also updates repository.
2. If you have enabled any PPAs before, but disable it now, **re-enable** it.
3. then do a `sudo apt-get update` to get updated package list
4. then do `sudo apt-get install winetricks`.

**Note that:** Many of the packages are getting removed not for the fact that, it is causing conflict with `winetricks` but because, they are automatically marked as obsolete because the cause of their installation (they were dependency of some KDE apps) is not available now. They will removed even if you don't install `winetricks`, but only do a `sudo apt-get autoremove` command. See this line in the output

> `The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:`

Hope this answer will help