# Is there a way to get rid of the default file manager for Xubuntu without having to get rid of the desktop?

Tags: xubuntu

I recently switched from Lubuntu to Xubuntu but I prefer Lubuntu's file manager, PCManFM, to Thunar, which is the default file manager in Xubuntu. So I installed PCManFM instead. Then I tried to uninstall Thunar via Synaptic but this process wants to uninstall other software as well, including "**xubuntu-desktop**".

[image: synaptic]

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe because of your bias. I think Thunar is awesome. PCManFM lacks a lot of features

Comment: hmm ok @function but it seems a bit pot kettle. Besides, I think it's fair to say thunar incorrectly labeling my filesizes as 4.1kb is a flaw. The files were not 4.1kb.

Comment: That said, I do take your point. I am sure thunar has some appeal to those who have different requirements to mine and in fairness PCManFM cannot display file sizes either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Removing `xubuntu-desktop` will actually do little.

`xubuntu-desktop` is only a metapackage.

This means that it has no files or code *whatsoever*, except for a control file that says it depends on thunar and other stuff, and possibly a bit of filler code. <sup>[Citation needed]</sup>. You can safely remove this package without losing anything, since all its installation did was pull in a ton of other packages, which actually make the Xubuntu interface work, that aren;t on the list of removals.

The reason it gets removed, is it "depends" on Thunar in order to get Thunar installed in a Xubuntu installation, so when Thunar is removed, `xubuntu-desktop` is als oremoved(without ill effect).

With that said, updates that add Xubuntu packages(uncommon) will go unnoticed, but updates on existing Xubuntu packages(common) *will* be performed.

Comment: Here goes nothing then! Aside from that I thought xubuntu-desktop was the environment therefore looked after panel etc. Can you please elaborate on this a bit, I am quite interested in learning something more about it.

Comment: and what about xfdesktop4. Will that eat into my panel and icons or am I safe to get rid of the rest of the thunar remains?

Comment: As already said `xubuntu-desktop`is nothing more than a meta package. If you remove  Thunar only those packages named `thunar`should be removed, `xfdesktop4` provides the Desktop (read, the Desktop itself not the whole Environment) and `xfce4-panel` provides, well... the panel.

Comment: Also I asked this http://askubuntu.com/questions/177752/why-does-synaptic-want-me-to-uninstall-half-my-programs-just-to-get-wine a while ago and never got a true answer. Different situation but I am wondering if this a similar deal to the one you just described here?

Comment: xubuntu-desktop is a "place holder" if you will, that makes the installation and upgrading of many packages easier, you tell the computer to install it and it installs hundreds of other packages, you un-install `xubuntu-desktop` and all it un-installs is `xubuntu-desktop` https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages

Answer (score 0):

In Xubuntu 16.04 when removing `thunar`, besides the packages you show in your question, also the package `xubuntu-core` is removed, but even when you remove it "nothing happens" (I did it).

So it is safe to remove `thunar` and associate dependences in Xubuntu.
However some thunar-related packages remain such as `libthunarx-2-0` and `thunar-data`. The removing of such packages is discouraged, as they force the removing of package `xfdesktop4`, which has an important display function.